# php: how to match multiple chars in a string using regex

Tags: php, regex

given that string

```
$opStr = "1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5";
preg_match('/[\+\-\*\/]/', $strOp, $matches);
```

$matches is

```
array (size=1)
    0 => string '+' (length=1)
```

basically it is matching the first operand, is there a way to know if the string contains more operand, like in this example?

thanks

expected outputs

```
case "1 + 1": $matches[0] = '+'
case "2 - 1": $matches[0] = '-'
case "1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5": $matches[0] = '+-+/'
or
case "1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5": $matches[0] = array('+', '-', '+', '/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `preg_match_all` function in-order to do a global match.

```
preg_match_all('~[-+*/]~', $strOp, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xW8kZ0/4)

```
$re = "~[-+*/]~m";
$str = "1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => +
            [1] => -
            [2] => *
            [3] => /
        )

)
```

Comment: in this case I get 0 => string '+ 1 *' (length=5), is there a way to have all operands in $matches array? or in a string? thanks

Comment: post the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **preg_match_all** instead of preg_match.

```
<?php

$opStr = "1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5";
preg_match_all('/[\+\-\*\/]/', $opStr, $matches);

echo '<pre>';print_r($matches);echo '</pre>';

## will produce:
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => +
        [1] => -
        [2] => *
        [3] => /
    )
)
*/
```